# VB script + replace word only in specific line

Tags: vbscript

I find way to replace word in text file as the following

strNewText = Replace(strText, "OLD_WORD", "NEW_WORD")t

but this replace every OLD_WORD in the file

my question is if it possible to replace the OLD_WORD with the NEW_WORD only on specific line

for example I want to replace only on line that start with "THIS_LOCATION"

THIS_LOCATION=OLD_WORD

THX for help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If InStr(strText, 'THIS_LOCATION') Then
  strNewText = Replace(strText, "OLD_WORD", "NEW_WORD")
End If
```

The **[`InStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28VS.80%29.aspx)** function first checks if the line contains `THIS_LOCATION` word and if found, it does the replace.

Comment: THX I will try it
did you read my last quastion about how to create check BOX?
yael

Comment: @yael: Your question is not clear there, i would simply say a check box is created like `<input type="checkbox" name="name" />`. Try to make your questions clear so that everyone understands your requirements and then you have higher chances of others responding back to you.

Comment: hi again somthing is wrong with systax can U please check it again

Comment: @yael: Yes, i was missing `Then` in `If` condition, fixed now.